# MySQL Query works but not within PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to simply display a value fetched via a query.

```
$newquery = "SELECT fullname FROM `users` WHERE user_id=" . $row['usernumber'];
$newresult=mysql_query($newquery);
$newrow = mysql_fetch_row($newresult);
echo "<td>" . $newrow[0]. "</td>";
```

(Where `$row['usernumber']` is fetched from a previous query.)

I get this error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /a/b/viewall.php on line 41
```

Which I presume, means that my query is failing because of some reason.

Here if I `echo $newquery;` I get

```
SELECT fullname FROM `users` WHERE user_id=3
```

And if I run this in mysql separately, it returns the `fullname` corresponding to `user_id=3` properly.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Your code is deprecated, check here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: add "or die(mysql_error())" with this query newresult=mysql_query($newquery);

Comment: What does [`mysql_error()`](http://us3.php.net/mysql_error) yield?

Comment: Try to add `if(!$newresult){ die(mysql_error()); }`

Comment: try to `echo` out `$newresult`

Answer (score 0):

For starters, put some error checking after mysql_query:

```
$newresult = mysql_query($newquery);
if (!$newresult) {
   die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always write PHP code to check the return value of `mysql_query()` (or equivalent function in mysqli or PDO).  It returns `false` if there's an error.  That's why you get the error you did, because $newresult was `false` -- not a legitimate query resource.

If mysql_query() returns false, you should report the error message and find out what's wrong.

```
$newquery = "SELECT fullname FROM `users` WHERE user_id=" . $row['usernumber'];
$newresult=mysql_query($newquery);
if ($newresult === false) { die(mysql_error()); }
$newrow = mysql_fetch_row($newresult);
```

For example, other errors are possible instead of syntax errors.  Perhaps you don't have the privileges needed to read that table when connecting from PHP, even though you do have the privileges when connecting in a direct query client.

Answer (score 0):

On my system, it works best to backtick all field/table names and to single-quote variables.

The addition of `mysql_error()` should also help you identify the error.

Note change to query text.

Try this:

```
$un = $row['usernumber'];

$newquery = "SELECT `fullname` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`= '$un'";
$newresult=mysql_query($newquery) or die(mysql_error());
$newrow = mysql_fetch_row($newresult);
echo "<td>" . $newrow[0]. "</td>";
```

Comment: backticks are only required when using field/table names that are otherwise invalid (e.g. `some-thing`) or are reserved words. they do not HAVE to be used everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It looks likely to be the connection / database selection code which precedes this code block.

As others have mentioned, Please look in to other database driver alternatives (mysqli or PDO)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$newquery = sprintf("SELECT fullname FROM `users` WHERE user_id=%d " ,$row['usernumber']);
$result = mysql_query($newquery);
if (!$result ) 
{
   die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
   //do something
}
```